# How to shade an image and keep the value assigned in it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how I can click on an image like this [image]

If I click on the BMW or Toyota logo then it shades the icon I have selected with CSS then keep that 'value' and save it in javascript variable so I can use later.

Let's say I have this

```
<ul class="car_types">
            <li class="bmw"><img src="test/bmw.png"></li>
            <li class="audi"><img src="test/audi.png"></li>
            <li class="toyota"><img src="test/toyota.jpg"></li>
            <li class="benz"><img src="test/benz.jpg">Discover</li>
        </ul>
```

or i have

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <div class="car_types">
        <img id="bmw" src="test/bmw.png">
        <img id="audi" src="test/audi.png">
        <img id="toyota" src="test/toyota.jpg">
        <img id="benz" src="test/benz.jpg">
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or any other way of doing it. 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you add a click listener to the image. This click listener then adds a `selected` class to the image. The image has styles which it applies when there is a `.selected` class on the image. These styles should then shade the image. The click listener also sets the JavaScript variable which you can then use.

Here is an example with plain JavaScript (no jQuery):

```js
var selectedCar = 'no car selected';
var allCarTypes = document.querySelectorAll('.car_type');

allCarTypes.forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var selectedElement = event.target;
    removeSelectedClassForAllElements();
    selectedElement.classList.add('selected');
    selectedCar = selectedElement.id;
  });
});


function removeSelectedClassForAllElements () {
  allCarTypes.forEach(function (item) {
     item.classList.remove('selected');
  });
}
```

```css
.car_type {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.car_type:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.car_type.selected:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible
}
```

```html
<div class="car_types">
   <img id="bmw" class="car_type" src="test/bmw.png">
   <img id="audi" class="car_type" src="test/audi.png">
   <img id="toyota" class="car_type" src="test/toyota.jpg">
   <img id="benz" class="car_type" src="test/benz.jpg">
</div>

<!-- do not use 'onclick' -->
<button onclick="alert(selectedCar);">Which car is selected?</button>
```

Comment: you missed the link to your example :)

Comment: I've added it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to each of your images, so that you can select which image should be highlighted.

Then, create a special css class which gives a special style to the selected image.

I've created a simple demo below:

---

Here, we have a listener that listens on the "click" event on the `<li>` elements inside of your `.car_types` list. When we do click on an image, we remove any elements that might have the `shaded` class (from a previous click), and then add the `shaded` class to the one we just clicked on.

The `shaded` class just gives a 50% brightness, instead of 100%.

```js
$(".car_types li").on("click", function(){
  $(".car_types li").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("shaded");
  });
  $(this).addClass("shaded");
});
```

```css
.car_types li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.shaded {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="car_types">
  <li class="bmw"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/135x135"></li>
  <li class="audi shaded"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/135x135"></li>
  <li class="toyota"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/135x135"></li>
  <li class="benz"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/135x135"></li>
</ul>
```

---

If you want to be able to shade several logos at once, try this instead:

```js
$(".car_types li").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("shaded")) {
    $(this).removeClass("shaded");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("shaded");
  }
});
```

```css
.car_types li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.shaded {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="car_types">
  <li class="bmw"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/135x135"></li>
  <li class="audi shaded"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/135x135"></li>
  <li class="toyota"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/135x135"></li>
  <li class="benz"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/135x135"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have added event listener like this,
Have a global variable in your js file and modify it on click event..

```
var selectedVal; //global variable for value
$(".car_types li").on("click", function(){
  $(".car_types li").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("shaded");
  });
  $(this).addClass("shaded");
  selectedVal=$(this).data("val"); //modifying global variable
});

//access selectedVal anywhere
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="car_types">
            <li class="bmw" data-val="bmw"><img src="test/bmw.png"></li>
            <li class="audi" data-val="audi"><img src="test/audi.png"></li>
            <li class="toyota" data-val="toyota"><img src="test/toyota.jpg"></li>
            <li class="benz" data-val="benz"><img src="test/benz.jpg">Discover</li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.shaded{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is with pure JS

```js
HTMLCollection.prototype.each = function(cb) {  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
  cb(this[i], i);
 }
}

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

imgs.each(function(img) {
  img.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
     imgs.each(function(img) {
       img.classList.remove('selected');
     });
     
     ev.target.classList.add('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  opacity: .8;
}

.selected {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="car_types">
            <li class="bmw"><img src="test/bmw.png"></li>
            <li class="audi"><img src="test/audi.png"></li>
            <li class="toyota"><img src="test/toyota.jpg"></li>
            <li class="benz"><img src="test/benz.jpg">Discover</li>
        </ul>
```